# Wamp local host defaults to IIS 7

Tags: wampserver

I have disabled IIS7 in my machine. installed WAMP server.  Stopped skype, antivirus which used port 80.  When i ran Wamp server, phpmyadmin is working great and when i click on localhost it is showing Default IIS7 page.  Can anyone please help me out , how can i avoid this and get wamp localhost.

Comment: Try the command line [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317(v=ws.10).aspx). Also be sure to clear your browser completely.

Answer (score 1):

First, you "might" have a virus on your machine pretending to be an antivirus and using port 80. If your antivirus uses port 80 I think you should delete it immediately and install Windows Defender, for example. An antivirus should not use port 80!

Second, WAMP might have automatically installed on another port since it might have found port 80 to be used while you where installing it. Try accessing it on port `8080` for example.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
http://localhost:8080/
```

Third, try to un-install everything, get a port scanner tool, make sure port `80` is free, then re-install WAMP.

Good luck.